# How set Mule_Correlation_ID using meassage chunk splitter

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-esb, mulesoft

Am feeding json data to scatter gatherer  and sending messages to two message chunk splitters after transforming one copy to csv data and another to fixed length  and setting "enable correlation id" to "always" option. But mule message chunk splitter  is setting  same  Mule_Correlation_id to both the json and csv data and in turn which is same as normal "correlation_id" don't understand why this happens even though I am setting enable correaltion id to "always" option. here is the screen shot of the flow.

[image]

above is the screen shot of the mule flow . here is the settings of message chunk splitter

[image]

is there any thing I need to change  to get different "mule_correlation_id".

Comment: What is the payload received by the splitter?

Comment: @aled It is json format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mule 3.x [splitter documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/splitter-flow-control-reference#aggregating-the-payload) mentions that it sets the following outbound properties:

- MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE: number of fragments into which the original message was split.
- MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE: position of a fragment within the group.
- MULE_CORRELATION_ID: single ID for entire group (all output fragments of the same original message share the same value).

All the parts splitted from the same original message will share the same MULE_CORRELATION_ID, so they can be related together. Each part should have a unique MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE within the same MULE_CORRELATION_ID.

Comment: Thank you. I got it